# FitNesse Upgrade to .Net 4.0 with Fitsharp: Real time Results Display

Tags: .net, fitnesse, fitsharp

I have a question concerning a difference I noticed between FiNesse and the newer version of FitNesse (with Fitsharp) to work with .Net 4.0.

When running tests with the older version of FitNesse the test results page showed each command's result as that particular command completed while the test was still running.

With the newer FitNesse/Fitshap I've noticed that my test completes before it reveals any results to me.

Is there a way to get the FitNesse/Fitsharp to show real time results?

Answer (score 1):

No, changes in the architecture of fitSharp to enable some of its new features meant that the results of a storytest are delivered back to FitNesse all at once rather than table by table.

Comment: Oh, this is quite unfortunate. We have over 200 people on our development team with over 10,000 tests which we run through FitNesse. We have just successfully upgraded to FitSharp and everything has gone really well. That results feature however is one thing we are missing. Is there possibly any way to add a progress bar so our testers can follow along with a test in that sense?

Comment: I'll put something in the next release. And when is the next release? When I get enough spare time to get it ready :)

Comment: Change is ready. A preview version is at https://github.com/jediwhale/fitsharp/downloads