# Fitnesse doesn't show progress

Tags: browser, fitnesse

When running any suite or single test I don't see the page in browser refreshed or with any progress. Tried in chrome and ie.

The suite runs ok, I can see it by the logs.

What can be the reason of this behavior?

Comment: What release of FitNesse are you using?  Slim, Fit, FitLibrary?  FitSharp or Java?  How many tables are on the page?  How big are the tables?

Comment: This is Java, a lot of tables in the suite, but tables aren't too big.

Comment: And the release number?  And which test system?

Comment: I'm not at work right now, I'll give you details at Sunday, is it ok?

Comment: It's Slim, with dot net plugin v 1.9 (tried with 1.8 also)

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862864/fitnesse-upgrade-to-net-4-0-with-fitsharp-real-time-results-display

I don't use the .Net stuff every day, but I remember seeing this post and your situation sounds similar.

Comment: Ok, there was a mistake; the cause of problem was fiddler web debugger running in background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) web debugger ate the traffic from fitnesse to browser.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running FitNesse on a different port? We experienced a similar problem and it was fixed by switching to another port number. Strange, but we suspect some kind of corporate software.

Comment: I've already figured out the problem, this behavior was caused by Fiddler web debugger