# Fitnesse does not show testing progress on Windows 7

Tags: fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I am using Fitnesse for our feature testing, but when running on windows 7, it does not show progress of my tests. It does not show progress bar nor completion of each test. I know that the test were ran only by inspecting logs. It works fine when running on windows 8. I also tried running on Linux distribution like CentOS and Ubuntu without any problems. 
There was a similar post before mentioning something about fiddler web debugger running in the background, but I don't think I am running fiddler in the first place. Link to the previous post -> [Fitnesse doesn't show progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923246/fitnesse-doesnt-show-progress)
Trying to run it on a different port does not fix the problem.

Comment: I run FitNesse on Windows 7 quite often, and I get progress bars. Which browser are you using? And which version of FitNesse?

Comment: I tried chrome, firefox, opera and IE. It does not work with any of them. I believe that I'm using the latest version of fitnesse, which is release 20150424. We have tried different PCs, but we still get the same problem.